# Present a confirmation dialog before casting a spam flag using keyboard shortcuts

Tags: feature-request, flags, keyboard-shortcuts

For the second time this year, I've accidentally flagged a non-answer as rude/abusive.

[image]

<kbd>2</kbd> is very close to <kbd>3</kbd>, at least on my keyboard. Muscle memory kicked in, and I hit enter right after accidentally hitting 2.

This isn't really a big deal, except that now I've added a high-priority item to the moderator flag queue. I'm also a somewhat reputable flagger, so this is likely to waste valuable moderator time ("There must have been a reason he flagged that").

This is all-around bad. Can we add a confirmation dialog to at least the rude/abusive option, and probably the spam option too? Flagging spam is rare enough that I can afford to hit enter one more time.

To clarify, I would suggest implementing this on *only* spam/rude/abusive flags, and *only* those cast via the keyboard shortcuts.

Thoughts?

Comment: Just change spam to 0 and offensive to 9. Instant mollyguard.

Comment: @Shog9 That'd be awesome too, and much easier.

Comment: I have to hit Enter before the flag is cast; doesn't that already count as a safeguard?